# Get inner text in html tags with Beatifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a inner text inside of a html tag with bs4
but i'm not familiar with the library. would be appreciated you guys help me .

html:

`<span class="course-time"> Duration<i> 3:1:00 </i></span>`

for example I'm using this code to get the text inside of ***i*** tag:

`duration = soup.findAll("span" , attrs = {"class" : {"course-time"}})[0].decode_contents()`

when I use this code, i get  the text but with i tag.

i just want the text.

how can i do so?

Comment: Just use `.text` instead of `.decode_contents()`

Comment: thankssolved the problem

Comment: Good to know. No need to use the emojis here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `.text`:

```
duration = soup.findAll("span" , attrs = {"class" : {"course-time"}})[0].text
```